# Reactive Plotly in R Shiny is producing odd looking data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive

I'm trying to create a plotly plot of a few variables from a csv file that gets updated hourly. The resulting graph is a straight 1:1 line for the pm_cor series, the other series are missing.

I'd like to eventually be able to turn series on and off, but for now, I just want to see my data looking as expected. I do need to perform some transformations on the data to get it corrected, so it has complicated the code a bit, but here's what I have:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(readr)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Sensors", disable = T),
    dashboardSidebar(
        disable = T,
        sidebarMenu()
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            box(width= 9, title = "Sensors", background = "black", plotlyOutput("plot1"))
        ),
        shinyjs::useShinyjs()
    )
)

percentage_difference <- function(value, value_two) {
    abs((value - value_two) / ((value + value_two) / 2)) * 100
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ez.read = function(file, ..., skip.rows=NULL, tolower=FALSE) {
        if (!is.null(skip.rows)) {
            tmp = readLines(file)
            tmp = tmp[-(skip.rows)]
            tmpFile = tempfile()
            on.exit(unlink(tmpFile))
            writeLines(tmp, tmpFile)
            file = tmpFile
        }
        result = read.csv(file, ...)
        if (tolower) names(result) = tolower(names(result))
        return(result)
    }
    
    data <- reactivePoll(1000 * 60 * 15, session,
                         checkFunc = function() { file.info("sensor.csv")$mtime},
                         valueFunc = function() {
                             data <- ez.read("sensor.csv", tolower = T)
                             data$time_stamp <- as_datetime(data$time_stamp)
                             names(data)[1] <- "date"
                             names(data)[5] <- "pm_a"
                             names(data)[6] <- "pm_b"
                             data$humidity <- as.numeric(data$humidity)

                             #only keep data where a and b are within 5, then perform correction factors based on the bin of their average
                             data <- data %>%
                                 mutate(pm_cor = case_when(
                                     abs(pm_a - pm_b) < 5 ~ 
                                         ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 30,
                                                0.524 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                                ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 50,
                                                       (0.786 * ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 20) - 3/2) + 0.524 * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 20) - 3/2))) * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                                       ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 210,
                                                              0.786 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                                              ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 260,
                                                                     (0.69 * ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5) + 0.786 * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5))) * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5)) + 2.966 * (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5) + 5.75 * (1 - (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5)) + 8.84 * 10^-4 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE)^2 * (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5),
                                                                     2.966 + 0.69 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) + 8.84 * 10^-4 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE)^2
                                                              )
                                                       )
                                                  )
                                                ),
                                                TRUE ~ NA_real_
                                         ))
                                     
                                     data$pdiff <- percentage_difference(data$pm_a,data$pm_b)
                                     data <- pivot_wider(data,names_from = sensor_index,values_from = c(humidity, temperature, pm_a, pm_b, pdiff,pm_cor))
                                     data
                         })
                            
                             output$table <- renderTable(data())
                             
                             
             
                             # Plot
                             output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
                                 plot_data <- data()
                                 plot_data <- plot_data %>% arrange(date)
                                 fig <- plot_ly()
                                 
                               
                                 fig <- add_trace(fig, x = plot_data$date, y = plot_data$pm_a, name = "pm_a_93325", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
                                 fig <- add_trace(fig, x = plot_data$date, y = plot_data$pm_b, name = "pm_b_93325", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
                                 fig <- add_trace(fig, x = plot_data$date, y = plot_data$pdiff, name = "pdiff_93325", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
                                 fig <- add_trace(fig, x = plot_data$date, y = plot_data$pm_cor, name = "pm_cor_93325", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
                                 
                                 
                                 fig <- layout(fig, title = "Sensor 93325 Data", xaxis = list(title = "Date"), yaxis = list(title = "Values"))
                                 
                                 fig
                             })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

sensor.csv snippet:

```
time_stamp,sensor_index,humidity,temperature,pm2.5_atm_a,pm2.5_atm_b
1697000400,93325,67.867,52.7,6.048,5.279
1697004000,93325,67.5,53.6,5.442,4.786
1697040000,93325,42.5,73.067,4.239,3.941
1697011200,93325,62.267,54.666,5.662,5.16
1696399200,93325,68.267,65.0,8.456,8.181
1696377600,93325,57.633,74.25,9.389,8.784
1696122000,93325,71.334,72.467,21.392,19.959
1696176000,93325,46.567,83.733,10.662,9.479
1696168800,93325,66.8,72.667,15.885,14.849
1696338000,93325,72.867,67.966,15.727,14.604
1696374000,93325,46.058,79.342,7.748,7.088
1696294800,93325,66.534,71.7,20.221,18.643
1696546800,93325,77.867,68.966,18.733,17.2
1696492800,93325,62.733,71.7,17.677,16.736
1696222800,93325,72.566,66.534,14.466,13.815
1696230000,93325,75.3,64.2,15.539,14.407
1696010400,93325,43.1,90.8,11.642,11.361
1695924000,93325,98.6,67.2,17.668,16.203
1696593600,93325,78.233,66.434,20.581,19.08
1696690800,93325,49.3,57.0,0.814,0.725
1696644000,93325,47.067,62.466,1.255,0.933
1696658400,93325,53.2,53.8,1.522,1.256
1696089600,93325,47.534,84.433,16.819,15.394
1696060800,93325,80.0,65.066,24.43,21.921
1696068000,93325,80.0,63.966,21.581,19.63
1696734000,93325,61.034,49.767,1.782,1.402
1696806000,93325,40.267,61.034,2.359,2.224
1696759200,93325,76.0,41.3,6.032,5.632
1696784400,93325,32.466,68.8,0.494,0.325
1696824000,93325,63.0,51.233,2.014,1.639
1696874400,93325,35.5,78.1,3.917,3.566
1696816800,93325,65.5,51.067,3.525,3.069
1696834800,93325,62.067,50.133,1.827,1.571
1696888800,93325,35.341,73.966,2.612,2.024
1697029200,93325,56.5,59.833,5.155,4.486
```

I do get a warning in the console:

```
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'pm_a'.
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column :'pm_b'.
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column :'pdiff'.
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column :'pm_cor'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your above code the `y` parameters of your `add_trace` calls don't meet the column names of your dataset (`plot_data`). Furthermore, in your resulting graph the other series are not missing - they are covered. Try clicking the legend items to see them.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(readr)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sensors", disable = T),
  dashboardSidebar(
    disable = T,
    sidebarMenu()
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width= 9, title = "Sensors", background = "black", plotlyOutput("plot1"))
    ),
    shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  )
)

percentage_difference <- function(value, value_two) {
  abs((value - value_two) / ((value + value_two) / 2)) * 100
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ez.read = function(file, ..., skip.rows=NULL, tolower=FALSE) {
    if (!is.null(skip.rows)) {
      tmp = readLines(file)
      tmp = tmp[-(skip.rows)]
      tmpFile = tempfile()
      on.exit(unlink(tmpFile))
      writeLines(tmp, tmpFile)
      file = tmpFile
    }
    result = read.csv(file, ...)
    if (tolower) names(result) = tolower(names(result))
    return(result)
  }
  
  data <- reactivePoll(1000 * 60 * 15, session,
                       checkFunc = function() { file.info("sensor.csv")$mtime},
                       valueFunc = function() {
                         data <- ez.read("sensor.csv", tolower = T)
                         data$time_stamp <- as_datetime(data$time_stamp)
                         names(data)[1] <- "date"
                         names(data)[5] <- "pm_a"
                         names(data)[6] <- "pm_b"
                         data$humidity <- as.numeric(data$humidity)
                         
                         #only keep data where a and b are within 5, then perform correction factors based on the bin of their average
                         data <- data %>%
                           mutate(pm_cor = case_when(
                             abs(pm_a - pm_b) < 5 ~ 
                               ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 30,
                                      0.524 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                      ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 50,
                                             (0.786 * ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 20) - 3/2) + 0.524 * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 20) - 3/2))) * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                             ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 210,
                                                    0.786 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity + 5.75,
                                                    ifelse(rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) < 260,
                                                           (0.69 * ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5) + 0.786 * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5))) * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) - 0.0862 * humidity * (1 - ((rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50) - 21/5)) + 2.966 * (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5) + 5.75 * (1 - (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5)) + 8.84 * 10^-4 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE)^2 * (rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) / 50 - 21/5),
                                                           2.966 + 0.69 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE) + 8.84 * 10^-4 * rowMeans(cbind(pm_a, pm_b), na.rm = TRUE)^2
                                                    )
                                             )
                                      )
                               ),
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_
                           ))
                         
                         data$pdiff <- percentage_difference(data$pm_a,data$pm_b)
                         data <- pivot_wider(data,names_from = sensor_index,values_from = c(humidity, temperature, pm_a, pm_b, pdiff,pm_cor))
                         data
                       })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(data())
  
  # Plot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_data <- data()
    plot_data <- plot_data %>% arrange(date)
    fig <- plot_ly(data = plot_data, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    
    fig <- add_trace(fig, x = ~ date, y = ~ pm_a_93325, name = "pm_a_93325")
    fig <- add_trace(fig, x = ~ date, y = ~ pm_b_93325, name = "pm_b_93325")
    fig <- add_trace(fig, x = ~ date, y = ~ pdiff_93325, name = "pdiff_93325")
    fig <- add_trace(fig, x = ~ date, y = ~ pm_cor_93325, name = "pm_cor_93325")
    
    
    fig <- layout(fig, title = "Sensor 93325 Data", xaxis = list(title = "Date"), yaxis = list(title = "Values"))
    
    fig
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Btw. instead of re-rendering the plot you could modify it via `plotlyProxyInvoke`, which is faster. Please see my related answer [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/6).

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that but the graph output gave me enough to scratch my head! I will have to look into the plotlyProxyInvoke, not sure how to work that into my code, I'm not proficient with Shiny yet.